# Image alignment within a row of divs

Tags: css, alignment

I have a row of divs which I would like the images to centre vertical and horizontally.

```
<div id="treatments-wrapper">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h2>Our Treatments</h2>
                </div>
                <div class="treatments-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/nouveau-logo.png" alt="nouveau logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="treatments-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/nouveau-logo.png" alt="nouveau logo"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="treatments-logo">
                    <a href="#"><img src="img/nouveau-logo.png" alt="nouveau logo"></a>
                </div>
            </div><!--treatments-wrapper-->




 #treatments-wrapper {
    width:960px;
    height:100px;
    float: left;
    margin: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: #373839 solid 10px;
}

.treatments-logo {
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 8px;
}

.treatments-logo img {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
}

.heading {
    width:960px;
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #373839;
    float: left;
    margin:
}
```

Here it is on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cpTJ4/)

For this example I have used the same image 3 times, but it will be a row of different logos, all with different height and widths. Can anyone suggest something I could try out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try display:table-cell; with vertical-align:middle;

```
.treatments-logo {
    width: 1%;
    display:table-cell;
    height: 60px;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works! I changed a couple of things to get it just how I needed it. http://jsfiddle.net/cpTJ4/3/

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you're after - I've removed the individual `div`'s for each image and made the `treatments-logo` class the container.

**HTML**

```
<div class="treatments-logo">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37491564/nouveau-logo.png" alt="nouveau logo"/>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37491564/nouveau-logo.png" alt="nouveau logo"/>
    </a>
    <a href="#">
        <img src="https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/37491564/nouveau-logo.png" alt="nouveau logo"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

I've then changed these two CSS classes to this:

**CSS**

```
.treatments-logo {
    height: 60px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
.treatments-logo img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6jGTW/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The logos were still aligning at the top though rather than the middle.